# R: using apply over two data.frames

Tags: r, apply

I want to use apply instead of a for-loop. The problem is, my for-loop uses two data.frames as an input. For example:

```
x <- data.frame(col1=c(1,NA,3,NA), col2=c(9,NA,11,12))
y <- data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3,4), col2=c(5,6,7,8))
output <- rep(NA,2)
for(i in 1:2)
{
  output[i] <- sum(is.na(x[,i]))+sum(y[,i])
}
```

The result here is, correctly c(12,27).

But if I try function and apply:

```
test <- function(vector1,vector2) sum(is.na(vector1))+sum(vector2)
apply(x,y,MARGIN=2,FUN=test)
```

With apply the result is c(38,37). 
How can I fix this?

Comment: `apply` cannot take multiple datasets as you showed.   You may need to loop over the columns, and then appply the function i.e. `sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) sum(is.na(x[,i]))+sum(y[,i]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mapply instead of apply:

```
x <- data.frame(col1=c(1,NA,3,NA), col2=c(9,NA,11,12))
y <- data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3,4), col2=c(5,6,7,8))
test <- function(vector1,vector2) sum(is.na(vector1))+sum(vector2)
mapply(test, x, y)

# col1 col2 
#   12   27
```

`?mapply`

Comment: Thank you! Does mapply always go columnwise?

Comment: `?mapply` tells you that it applies `FUN`(in this case `test`) with the first elements of both `x`and `y` as arguments first, and the second elements second, and so on.  Since `data.frame`s are lists (`is.list(data.frame())`) with the columns as elements, it goes column wise.

Comment: mapply however will convert your data.frame into a matrix and if your data frames have different data types, like integer and character, everything will be converted into character.

Comment: That's true.  In this case I would refer to the `purrr` package and its various `map_*()` functions, if the problem is desired to be solved in this fashion.  Although we are doing sums here anyway so there should be no character around.